# Class 'Anonymous class derived from MessageListener' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method

Tags: android

I am new to XMPP world. I am trying to connect Open Fire Server installed on localhost through emulator installed on same machine. So far I am able to connect to Server however while trying to send message from Emulator to Server got error on the use of MessageListener() SMACK class. below is the error I got :-

"Class 'Anonymous class derived from MessageListener' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'processMessage(Message)' in 'MessageListener'"

Tried to google up but did not able to trace out why this error is coming.
Below are code I write:-

```
   private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String textResult;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) throws XMPPException {

        // run your networking code here
        // Create the configuration for this new connection
        XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder configBuilder =     
         XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();         
        configBuilder.setSecurityMode   
           (ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);            
        configBuilder.setServiceName("fire");
        configBuilder.setHost("10.0.2.2");
        configBuilder.setPort(5222);
        configBuilder.setCompressionEnabled(false);
        configBuilder.setResource("kenta");
        configBuilder.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
        configBuilder.setUsernameAndPassword("kenta@fire", "fire");

        AbstractXMPPConnection connection = new 
    XMPPTCPConnection(configBuilder.build());
        // Connect to the server
        try {
            connection.connect();
        } catch(SmackException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            textResult = e.toString();
        } catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            textResult = e.toString();
        }
        catch (XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            textResult = e.toString();
        }
   // Log into the server
        try {
            connection.login();
            // Assume we've created an XMPPConnection name "connection"._
            ChatManager chatmanager =   
    ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
            Chat newChat = chatmanager.createChat("jsmith@jivesoftware.com", 
        new MessageListener() {
                public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
                    System.out.println("Received message: " + message);
                }
            });

            newChat.sendMessage("Howdy!");


        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            textResult = e.toString();
        } catch (SmackException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            textResult = e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            textResult = e.toString();
        }
     // Disconnect from the server
        //connection.disconnect();
  return null;
  }
```

Thnx in advance for your help.

Comment: make sure you imported the right class, also your IDE can help which methods are not implemented.

Comment: I am not getting error due to not picking right classes. I am currently using Android Studio 1.2.2 and using Gradle to Build project. Unable to find the source of error. Let me know if other information is required.

Answer (score 2):

Able to resolve error by replacing MessageListener() with ChatMessageListener(). Under SMACK 4.1 release, MessageListener has been renamed to ChatMessageListener. Attention: MessageListener still exists with a different interface contract!

It is recommended to check latest release doc for classes before using codes given as part of solution on various websites.

Thank You all for helping me and giving due time in resolving issues.

Comment: Thx, that worked :)
But I can't understand why the official documentation is still using the MessageListener